# Aligning text in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

So I have some text, an Html.LabelFor on the left, and some raw text (as @Html.DisplayText simply does not work).

[image]

I end up with the above awfulness. I've tried to set the div alignment explicitly, to no avail. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="form-group" style="align-items:center">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.seniority, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Model.seniority.ToString()

    </div>
```

Comment: Put `@Model.seniority` (note you do not need `.ToString()`) inside a `<div>` and add padding and/or margins to match the css of the `<label>` element. But note that its not really a `<label>` because its not associated with a form control - clicking on it does not set focus to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach you should use when using bootstrap

```
 <div class="form-group" style="align-items:center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.seniority)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            @Model.seniority
    </div>
    </div>
```